# mapping a texture on a square (Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, vertices

Im new to openGL, and im trying to map an texture to a square. I followed NeHe's tutorial on texture mapping here:
http://insanitydesign.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/lesson06.zip

Right now i see my image...but its not mapping correctly. Heres the original image:
http://ge.tt/2FzsdIx

...and heres what im seeing.
http://ge.tt/6y3cdIu

I used the vertices and texture arrays from this great iphone tutorial (link below) so im hoping they have been mapped correctly. Below is the link to my code in Square.java, thanks!

```
public class Square {
// Our vertices.
private float vertices[] = {
          -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // 0, Top Left
          -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 1, Bottom Left
           1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 2, Bottom Right
           1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // 3, Top Right
    };

// The order we like to connect them.
private short[] indices = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

// Our vertex buffer.
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

// Our index buffer.
private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;


/** The buffer holding the texture coordinates */
private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;

//the texture pointer, holds the texture name which is actually a number.
private int[] textures = new int[1];

public Square() {
    // a float is 4 bytes, therefore we multiply the number if
    // vertices with 4.
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // short is 2 bytes, therefore we multiply the number if
    // vertices with 2.
    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
    indexBuffer.put(indices);
    indexBuffer.position(0);

    //plot our texture
    float textCoords[]={
            //Mapping coordinates for the vertices
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f

                                };
    ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textCoords.length * 4); tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer(); textureBuffer.put(textCoords);
    textureBuffer.position(0);

}

//load our texture(s)
static void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context context, int resource) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),resource);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
    gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR); 
    gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    bmp.recycle();      
}


/**
 * This function draws our square on screen.
 * @param gl
 */
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    //use our textures
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); // workaround bug 3623
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    // Counter-clockwise winding.
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW); // OpenGL docs
    // Enable face culling.
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // OpenGL docs
    // What faces to remove with the face culling.
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK); // OpenGL docs

    // Enabled the vertices buffer for writing and to be used during
    // rendering.
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);// OpenGL docs.
    // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
    // coordinates to use when rendering.
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, // OpenGL docs
                             vertexBuffer);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,// OpenGL docs
              GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);

    // Disable the vertices buffer.
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); // OpenGL docs
    // Disable face culling.
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // OpenGL docs

    }

}
```

iPhone tutorial:
http://www.iphonemobilephones.com/opengl-es-from-the-ground-up-part-6-textures-and-texture-mapping.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw faster using a triangle fan, in the following order in your indices, faster.

```
01
32
```

Then you don't need to use drawElements or indices, you can just feed it to drawArrays and only need 4 elements.

Your bug is that the , the tex coords are wrong

```
tl is 0,0
bl is 0,1
br is 1,1
tr is 1,0
```

You have

```
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f
```

So your UV is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Normally the rendering of a square in OpenGL looks something like this

```
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
gl.glBegin(GL_QUADS)
   glVertex(x,y,z);
   glTexcoord2f(s,t);
   glVertex(-x,y,z);
   glTexcoord2f(-s,t);
   glVertex(-x,-y,z);
   glTexcoord2f(-s,-t);
   glVertex(x,-y,z);
   glTexcoord2f(s,-t);
gl.glEnd();
```

I don't see anything like that, but I have never done GLES on Android before so I may be too old.

see https://github.com/ChrisLundquist/Asteroids/blob/master/src/ScenePanel.java#L277

Comment: there is no glBegin glVertex or any of that in android, you have to use vertex buffers.